# How to make a Angular Material Dialog component stay on top of other components

Tags: angular, angular-material

My app is set up to use a vertical Navigation Bar on the left of the screen and a Home Component in the `<router-outlet>` to the right of it.
When I open a Dialog Component in the Home Component part of it is hidden by the Navigation Bar which is on top of the Dialog Component. I’d like to keep the position of the Dialog Component relative to the whole screen not just to the Home Component in `<router-outlet>`.
The Navigation Bar does have CSS:

```
.main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying a prebuilt theme to `style.css` solved the problem:

`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to move the Dialog Component out of router outlet and use a service to open it up and close it. This way it is always on top.

If you don't want to do that, you need to use `position:absolute` on the Dialog bring in on top.